# progressbar(прогрессбар) и GMT

Tags: javascript

Есть progressbar на JavaScript. Работает отлично, но если часовой пояс отличный от времени сервера начинает работать не точно. Если разница 5 часов, то и показывает на прогрессбаре не сутки допустим, а 19 часов. А должно 24 часа.

Вопрос: **как победить GMT на JavaScript?** Или я в не ту сторону думаю?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.fn.anim_progressbar = function(aOptions) {
    // Определяем значения
    var iCms = 1000;
    var iMms = 60 * iCms;
    var iHms = 3600 * iCms;
    var iDms = 24 * 3600 * iCms;


    // Определяем опции
    var aDefOpts = {
      //var date = new Date(2013, 7, 15, 12, 45, 12);
      //document.write(date);
      //start: new Date(2015, 8, 8, 14, 30, 12), // Текущее время
      start: new Date( <? php echo $startd; ?> ),
      //finish: new Date().setTime(new Date().getTime() + 1500 * iCms), // Текущее время  + 60 сек
      //finish: new Date(2015, 8, 8, 15, 30, 12),
      finish: new Date( <? php echo $datat; ?> ),

      interval: 100
    }

    var aOpts = jQuery.extend(aDefOpts, aOptions);
    var vPb = this;

    // Кажды индикаторо прогресса
    return this.each(
      function() {
        var iDuration = aOpts.finish - aOpts.start;

        // Вызываем оригинальны йиндикатор прогресса
        $(vPb).children('.pbar').progressbar();

        // Процесс обработки
        var vInterval = setInterval(
          function() {

            var iLeftMs = aOpts.finish - new Date(); // Оставшееся врмея в миллисекундах
            var iElapsedMs = new Date() - aOpts.start, // Прошедшее время в миллисекундах
              iDays = parseInt(iLeftMs / iDms), // Прошло дней
              iHours = parseInt((iLeftMs - (iDays * iDms)) / iHms), // Прошло часов
              iMin = parseInt((iLeftMs - (iDays * iDms) - (iHours * iHms)) / iMms), // Прошло минут
              iSec = parseInt((iLeftMs - (iDays * iDms) - (iMin * iMms) - (iHours * iHms)) / iCms), // Прошло секунд
              iPerc = (iElapsedMs > 0) ? iElapsedMs / iDuration * 100 : 0; // Процент выполнения

            // Выводим текущее положение и прогресс
            $(vPb).children('.percent').html('<b>' + iPerc.toFixed(1) + '%</b>');
            $(vPb).children('.elapsed').html('Осталось ' + iDays + ' дн. ' + iHours + ' ч. ' + iMin + ' мин.:' + iSec + ' сек.</b>');
            $(vPb).children('.pbar').children('.ui-progressbar-value').css('width', iPerc + '%');

            // В случае завершения
            if (iPerc >= 100) {
              clearInterval(vInterval);
              $(vPb).children('.percent').html('<b>100%</b>');
              $(vPb).children('.elapsed').html('Завершено');

              setTimeout(
                function() {
                  location.reload();
                }, 4000
              );


            }
          }, aOpts.interval
        );
      }
    );
  }

  // Режим по умолчанию
  $('#progress1').anim_progressbar();

  // Для секунд с 5-й по 15-ю
  var iNow = new Date().setTime(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 1000); // Теперь прибавляем по 5 секунд
  var iEnd = new Date().setTime(new Date().getTime() + 15 * 1000); // Теперь прибавляем по 15 секунд
  $('#progress2').anim_progressbar({
    start: iNow,
    finish: iEnd,
    interval: 100
  });

  // Устанавливаем интервал обновления в 1 секунду
  $('#progress3').anim_progressbar({
    interval: 1000
  });
});
```

Comment: Попробуйте все расчеты делать в часовом поясе UTC, как на сервере при записи начального и конечного времени, так и на компьютере юзера.

Comment: Как это сделать? Данные start: new Date( <? php echo $startd; ?> ), и finish: new Date( <? php echo $datat; ?> ), берутся с базы данных. Заносятся туда по времени сервера. Но если плюсануть 3 часа, то програс бар выравнивается, а вот Надпись осталось N часов нет, так же сбита. Но если плюсовать 3 часа, для других юзеров будет другое время.

Comment: Либо используйте функции, которые возвращают значения в UTC часовом поясе, либо пересчитывайте время через смещение часового пояса `getTimezoneOffset()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Я с JS не дружу, куда что нужно вставить?

Comment: Например, вот так вот, при помощи `getTimezoneOffset()`, всё время должно быть в UTC (если и на сервере UTC). http://jsfiddle.net/L7Lsvzan/

Comment: *60 - это типо плюс один час?

Comment: Не сработало! (  NaN дн. NaN ч. NaN мин.:NaN сек.

Comment: I need help! (((

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Можно в архив!!!